# Sequential execution of threads freezes

Tags: java, multithreading, volatile

This code:

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test t = new Test();
        My1 m1 = new My1(t);
        My2 m2 = new My2(t);
    }
}

class Test {
    enum State {
        one, two, three
    }
    int i;
    volatile State state = State.one;
    synchronized void one() {
        while(state != State.one)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        i++;
        out.println("One: "+i);
        state = State.two;
        notify();
    }
    synchronized void two() {
        while(state != State.two)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        i++;
        out.println("Two: "+i);
        state = State.three;
        notify();
    }
    synchronized void three() {
        while(state != State.three)
            try {
                wait();
            } catch(InterruptedException e) {}
        i++;
        out.println("Three: "+i);
        state = State.one;
        notify();
    }

}
class My1 implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    Test test;
    My1(Test tst) {
        test = tst;
        t = new Thread(this, "My1");
        t.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        out.println(t);
        while(true)
            test.one();
    }
}
class My2 implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    Test test;
    My2(Test tst) {
        test = tst;
        t = new Thread(this, "My2");
        t.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        out.println(t);
        while(true)
            test.two();
    }
}
class My3 implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    Test test;
    My3(Test tst) {
        test = tst;
        t = new Thread(this, "My3");
        t.start();
    }
    public void run() {
        out.println(t);
        while(true)
            test.three();
    }
}
```

It does not work as I need. After starting, One and Two are displayed and the program freezes. I used volatile and it did not help me. Please help sort it out and make this code work.
(I watched similar answers and they didn’t suit me, I need to get this code to work without refactoring it)

Comment: use `noitfyAll()`. You can't be sure that thread 3 should wake up if you only use `notify()`.

Comment: Where do you create `My3`?

Comment: Johannes Kuhn, Here I forgot to include it in the code, but the same hang happens with it

Comment: And when you replace all `notify()` calls with `notifyAll()` as well?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you will not ever get to your `notify()` method calls because there is a `wait()` call before each one of them.  The `wait()` call will never allow the `notify()` methods to be called.

Here is a decent explanation of what is happening when the wait() method is called: [Difference Between Wait and Sleep in Java](https://www.baeldung.com/java-wait-and-sleep)